# Does a VB6 class have a destructor?

Tags: class, vb6

When I execute a statement such as

```
Set MyObject = Nothing
```

is there a particular function inside the class that is invoked (i.e. that I can use as a destructor), to do things like clean up arrays, disconnect from databases, and so forth?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Analogous to `Class_Initialize`, the constructor, there's also a destructor:

```
Sub Class_Terminate
    ... ' Put your destructor code here '
End Sub
```

This method is executed as soon as the reference count of this object reaches zero, i.e., when all variables that reference this object have gone out of scope or have been set to set to something else (e.g. `Nothing`). Thus, `Set MyObject = Nothing` will only call the destructor if `MyObject` is the last variable referencing this object.

Comment: +1:  This was bugging me for a while.  You've put my mind at rest :o)

Comment: As much as I like using VB6, this has its downsides. For example it isn't called if the program crashes (unhandled exceptions, End statement executed, etc.) so don't rely on it to unlock files, flush final buffers, etc.

Comment: +1 Just like it says [in the manual topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445560(v=VS.60).aspx). @Bob An alternative approach is to ban the `End` statement and allow `Class_Terminate` - it's useful and `End` is evil. When you say unhandled exceptions, do you mean unhandled native VB6 errors? Is it correct that `Class_Terminate` doesn't fire in those situations - can't remember offhand? We're pretty obsessive about error handlers so unhandled exceptions are rare these days (famous last words)

Answer (score -1):

No. VB6 does not provide any mechanism to the programmer to write something explicitly. What a programmer can do is `Set MyObject = Nothing` and VB will take care of the rest.

**UPDATE:**

One can use the `Class_Terminate` to handle this

Comment: Incorrect. The `Class_Terminate` method is fired when an object goes out of scope or is set to `Nothing`.