# Class_Terminate in VB6 Implementations

Tags: class, vb6

Following on from this question [Does a VB6 class have a destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749381/does-a-vb6-class-have-a-destructor) , I am attempting to create a Class_Terminate method in a class that implements an interface. But I can't find any way to get it to compile, since the method name

```
MyImplementation_Class_Terminate
```

perforce includes an underscore character, which one can't have in implementation method names (according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262287(VS.60).aspx).

Does anyone know what I should do to get this to work?

Comment: All concrete classes have a `Class_Terminate` event anyhow so there would be no need to enforce this requirement via the interface (if it were actually possible!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Class_Terminate` method isn't part of the interface.

```
''In class MyInterface
Public Sub Method()  '' method on the interface
End Sub 

''In class MyImplementation
Implements MyInterface 
Private Sub MyInterface_Method() 
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub
```